# How can add multiple color in Android circular seek bar Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-studio-2.0, android-seekbar, android-vertical-seekbar

How can we set multiple colors in android circular seek bar.
I need to add three colors with different percentage at run time.
Please suggest

Comment: try this example:https://github.com/jakob-grabner/Circle-Progress-View

Comment: Try this sample code. Hope it helps!! http://tutorialsface.blogspot.in/2014/09/gradient-circular-progress-bar-tri-color.html